# Sushi plotBedgraph and plotBed functions produce errors

Tags: r, plot

I wanted to plot my data in bedgraph and bed file formats using plotBedGraph and plotBed functions of Sushi package. I produced both files from my bam files using Bedtools. Additionally, I ran Example datasets provided by Sushi package to see if my package installation and dependencies are present and functioning and everything worked fine.
I imported my bedgraph file and used plotBedgraph function to plot the dataset as follows:

````
# import bedgraph file
```A24H1.bedgraph <- read.delim("A24H1.bedgraph", header = FALSE)```
# rename colnames according to Sushi example dataset
```colnames(A24H1.bedgraph) <- c("chrom", "start", "end", "value")```
# plot data
```chrom = "Chr"```
```chromstart = 0```
```chromend = 10835```
```plotBedgraph(A24H1.bedgraph,chrom,chromstart,chromend,colorbycol = SushiColors(5))```
# the function produced the following error:
[1] "not enough data within range to plot"
````

I checked the structure of my bedgraph file as follows:

````
```str(A24H1.bedgraph)```

'data.frame':   6162 obs. of  4 variables:

$ chrom: Factor w/ 1 level "TBEV_Hypr_(TEU39292)": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ start: int  0 1 4 16 17 18 24 25 26 27 ...

$ end  : int  1 4 16 17 18 24 25 26 27 28 ...

$ value: int  5 6 10 8 5 8 11 55 57 58 ...
````

The bedgraph structure corresponds to that of example bedgraph file provided by Sushi package.
I also extracted the mapped reads from my bamfile and mapped them in Geneious to see that the reads actually map to my reference so I know that there is enough reads to be mapped.

Additionally I experienced an error when using plotBed function:

````
# import bedgraph file
```A24H1.bed <- read.delim("A24H1.bed",header = FALSE)```
# rename colnames according to Sushi example dataset
```colnames(A24H1.bed) <- c("chrom", "start", "end", "name", "score", "strand")```
```chrom = "Chr"```
```chromstart = 0```
```chromend = 10833```
```plotBed(beddata = A24H1.bed,chrom = chrom,chromstart = chromstart,chromend = chromend,colorby = A24H1.bed$strand,colorbycol = SushiColors(2),row = "auto",wiggle = 0.001)```
# the function produced the following error:
Error in seq.default(min(vec), max(vec), length.out = num) :

  'from' must be a finite number

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In min(vec) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA

2: In max(vec) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA

Additionally, I also checked the structure of my bed file as follows:

``` str(A24H1.bed)```

'data.frame':   49000 obs. of  6 variables:

 $ chrom : chr  "TBEV_Hypr_(TEU39292)" "TBEV_Hypr_(TEU39292)" "TBEV_Hypr_(TEU39292)" "TBEV_Hypr_(TEU39292)" ...

 $ start : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 4 4 4 4 ...

 $ end   : int  17 17 42 16 16 17 36 36 36 36 ...

 $ name  : chr  "HISEQ:1014:CCU0AANXX:1:1107:9256:84705" "HISEQ:1014:CCU0AANXX:1:1109:3798:5998" "HISEQ:1014:CCU0AANXX:1:1307:20106:47604" "HISEQ:1014:CCU0AANXX:1:1310:6646:43722" ...

 $ score : int  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 ...

 $ strand: chr  "+" "+" "+" "-" ...
````

I am an R beginner and I don't know how else I can find where the problem is. I will be happy for any advice as I have been googling for similar issues for many hours and nobody else seems to have any problem with these Sushi functions. Thank you

Comment: It seems like `chrom = "Chr"` would assign the non-existing chromosome name `Chr`, so there is no data to plot. Try `chrom = "TBEV_Hypr_(TEU39292)"`...

Comment: thank you for your advise! that did work! it solved completely the plotbedgraph function problem; however, the plotBed function produced this error message: 
Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors, 
So I manually transformed "strand" column character values "+" and "-" to "1" and "-1" numeric values although Sushi manual allows for both. However, when I ran the plotBed function with this adjusted dataset the command keeps running without any response

Comment: By default (at least in the current R version, read.delim reads data with the option `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. Try `A24H1.bed <- read.delim("A24H1.bed",header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: Unfortunately `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, produced several errors:
`A24H1.bed1 <- read.delim("A24H1.bed", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
`plotBed(beddata = A24H1.bed1,chrom = chrom,chromstart = chromstart,chromend = chromend,colorby = A24H1.bed1$strand,colorbycol = SushiColors(2),row = "auto",wiggle = 0.001)`
[1] "yes"
Error in seq.default(min(vec), max(vec), length.out = num) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning message:
In seq.default(min(vec), max(vec), length.out = num) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: an update on plotBed function: I let the command for plotBed function running overnight and came to my office the other day and found the desired graph! Eventually, all the adjustments that I did to my input bed file were valid and correct, it just took more than 1 hour to my RStudio to deal with the function. THANK YOU for your great help and advisory!

Comment: the first comment could be posted as an answer to my problem. If possible, please, post that first comment as an answer or I can do it myself if this post is relevant and helpful enough for other users. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just re-posting this as an answer, per request:

`chrom = "Chr"` in the posted code would assign the non-existing chromosome name `Chr`, so there is no data to plot. Using `chrom = "TBEV_Hypr_(TEU39292)"` instead should solve this issue.